# Range of Salesforce IP address

Tags: salesforce-support

I need to communicate with and external service.  I am currently on a developer org.  The external service needs to whitelist the IP addresses of my Salesforce Organisation.  How shall I proceed to get the range of IP address.of my Salesforce Organisation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can read the help article [What are the Salesforce IP Addresses & Domains to whitelist?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1) for more details. It tells you which IP rnages you should whitelist based on your location.

Comment: Is this really the best way though? It would allow other Orgs from same region to ping service we're trying to secure

Comment: @user2402616 The load balancing features means it's hard to pin down definitively just which IP addresses you'll encounter. Whitelisting should not be your only line of defense. Consider peer SSL authentication, API keys, or other solutions. Remember, your org does not have your own dedicated IP address; even if you were to lock it down to just the IPs your instance uses, other users of that instance could still access your API if a whitelist is the only thing stopping them.